# Append text to top of file using sed doesn't work for variable whose content has "/"

Tags: bash, sed

Trying to append a import file path to files, doesn't work, and here is a simple repro:

I tried `haha="a/b/c/d/e"; sed -i '1s/^/"'$haha'"\n/' /tmp/processing.sh;` , it doesn't work, and gave me this error:
*sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown option to `s'*

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Change the `/` to something else like a pipe `|` , e.g. `sed ... 's|...|...|'`

Comment: doesn't work for me, how should I change sed -i '1s/^/"'$haha'"\n/'?

Comment: If you can't change the `/` to a pipe `|` from your `sed` syntax then sorry I can't help. I already have a sample code for you. Just replace the `/` to a pipe `|`. Also shell variables does not expand in single quotes.

Comment: One doesn't particularly need `sed` for this at all. `{ echo "new first line"; cat file.txt; } >"file.txt.$$" && mv -- "file.txt.$$" file.txt`

Comment: Or `printf "%s\n" 1i "$haha" . w | ed -s /tmp/processing.sh`